# TypeScript - what is the 'unique' keyword for?

Tags: typescript

I'm just writing some code in the TypeScript playground, and found that `unique` appears to be a reserved word, but I can't find any documentation for it.

[image]

Is there any documentation on this keyword anywhere?

Comment: `unique` isn't a keyword, it's the variable name, which holds an array of `Person`

Comment: @Carcigenicate in this case yes. but it's blue which suggests that it's a keyword

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol

Comment: @PatrickRoberts when why is it blue?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15473

Comment: Note that while the colorizer thinks this is a keyword, it is valid to use it as a variable name in this context. Only when used in a type expression is it truly a keyword

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.7 there is a `unique symbol` type which is used to allow using symbols as unique literals.  The relevant documentation is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol), and @TitianCernicovaDragomir linked the relevant [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15473) that introduced this functionality.

---

As for why it's blue in the Playground, I guess its colorization isn't the best and just highlights any special word even if it's not being used in a special context.  (I can't find a relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about it; maybe someone should file one?).  It's definitely a valid identifier, and the emitted JavaScript is correct.  VSCode doesn't seem to have this issue:

Compare [Playground weird colorizing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=const%20regular%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22hey%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20unique%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22you%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20string%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22guys%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20z%3A%20unique%20symbol%20%3D%20Symbol%28%29%3B):

[image: weird Playground colors]

to VSCode expected colorizing:

[image: VSCode colors]

Oh well.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 6):

This can be used with symbols. From the [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol):

> To enable treating symbols as unique literals a new type `unique symbol` is available. `unique symbol` is are subtype of `symbol`, and are produced only from calling `Symbol()` or `Symbol.for()`, or from explicit type annotations. The new type is only allowed on `const` declarations and `readonly static` properties, and in order to reference a specific unique symbol, you’ll have to use the `typeof` operator. Each reference to a `unique symbol` implies a completely unique identity that’s tied to a given declaration.

```
// Works
declare const Foo: unique symbol;

// Error! 'Bar' isn't a constant.
let Bar: unique symbol = Symbol();

// Works - refers to a unique symbol, but its identity is tied to 'Foo'.
let Baz: typeof Foo = Foo;

// Also works.
class C {
    static readonly StaticSymbol: unique symbol = Symbol();
}
```

Comment: `Symbols` are unique by nature, so I'm not completely clear on why the need for the `unique` modifier? It seems superfluous. What concept am I missing that makes the need for `unique` in addition to `Symbol` please?

Comment: @atconway: It is a way of declaring a literal akin to e.g. `const x: 'test'`. If you want to assign a different value than `test` to `x` you would get an error, also comparisons will be checked. Similarly if you have a variable that is just typed as `symbol` you can assign any symbol to it and compare it with any symbol. If you e.g. use `const a: unique symbol` and try to compare that with another unique symbol in an if condition you get an error stating: `This condition will always return 'false' ...`. So in essence it allows for a few more checks by narrowing the type.